# Does my tax refund need to be as close to zero dollars as possible?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax-refund

Am I doing my taxes wrong? I am receiving around 1000 dollars in tax refund, and someone tells me it should be as close as to zero as possible, I thought the tax refund was government giving back most of the taxes that have been taken out of our paycheck? I guess I have been doing it wrong to maximize my refund? I only made ~9000 last year.

Comment: If your income for 2015 was only $9000, and it included wages or salary or self-employment income, you may be eligible for the [Earned Income Tax Credit](https://www.irs.gov/Credits-&-Deductions/Individuals/Earned-Income-Tax-Credit) or EITC.  As that web page says, "EITC reduces the amount of tax you owe and may give you a refund."  If you have included this item on the tax return you are preparing (or have submitted already), that may be reason for the large refund. If you _haven't_ included the EITC, look into it and see if you are eligible to use it: you might get an every bigger refund.

Comment: I did eic, and I was eligible for 400 dollars, but that 400 dollars was never put on top of my 1000, I am not sure why.

Comment: A lot of people just think they get a refund after taxes and that's just how it is. This is wrong - you only get a refund if you paid more in taxes throughout the year than you were legally responsible for. Yes, many people do overpay, which is why they get a refund. If you paid the right amount, you'd get no refund (which is good actually), and if you paid too little, you get a bill. A refund isn't guaranteed nor automatic. One shouldn't plan what to do with their refund - rather one should plan how not to get a refund next year.

Comment: @SnakeDoc I think that perspective is somewhat silly.  Or at least, there are certainly people who _like_ getting a substantial refund each year.  And unless we're talking about _very_ large amounts, points about interest/the time-value of money are more pedantic than practical.  Even if you could get a guaranteed 5% interest rate on your cash (good luck with the current fiscal settings), you're talking about an extra ~$50 on a $1000 refund (and that's only if the government has the full amount, for a full year).

Comment: @aroth - I don't see where SnakeDoc ever mentioned interest. The point is that you gave your money to the government when you didn't need to. Think about it for a second, If I were to go to you and say please give me $1000 aroth and I promise I will pay you your $1000 back next April. If you were very confident that I would really pay you back, do you think that's a good idea? If not, why? If you answer the why then you know exactly why getting a big refund is not good for most people. However, if you have no discipline to save, then it is a good way to force no-interest savings on yourself.

Comment: @Dunk Getting a bit less every month and in return getting a larger sum once per year is actually a reasonably attractive proposition to some for purely psychological reasons (it's obviously not a rational choice). Basically I don't really notice having $100 more or less in my paycheck every month, but a $1200 "surprise" is fun!

Comment: @Voo why not open a savings account, and have a few percent of your paycheck automatically deposited there? If you open this account with a bank you don't do your normal banking with, it will be easier to "forget" about it and not be tempted to touch it. At the end of a year, you'll wind up with as much money saved, plus a smidgen of interest. After it's built to a reasonable level, you can open a Money Market account and collect more "interest", or invest it in a brokerage account, etc. Basically, there's a thousand ways to be more smart with your money than to lend it gratis to the gov't.

Comment: @Snake Yes very rational, now if only humans were actually rational actors (the most ridiculous assumption that economists just *love* to make). Don't construe this as sensible investment advice, just as an attempt at explaining observed behavior.

Comment: @Voo - Good money managers would rather have the option to use their money when they want, not only every April. That is the reason why people say to try and get as close to $0 as possible with your tax refund. However, like you said, people being people are generally not good money managers. Thus, that $100 a month would end up just getting wasted, whereas the $1200 lump sum might turn into something worthwhile. But that's a people problem and not an advice on the best way to manage your money problem, which is try to get that return as close to $0 as possible.

Comment: This sort of discussion makes me so glad of PAYE and automatic tax calculations.

Comment: @Dunk Does the US have anything similar to [GICs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guaranteed_Investment_Certificate)?  (I assume yes.)  It can be a better way for the weak-willed to store their money away from themselves for a year, getting at least some sort of a return (though it can be quite small with a term of only a year).

Comment: I personally feel better overpaying my taxes and getting a small refund than risking owing a significant amount. You can't get around it, so you may as well make sure the pain is minimal.

Comment: "he bottom line is that a refund is money you lend the government, interest free." If you had stuck the money in a checking account, you'd be giving your bank a nearly interest-free loan.

Comment: somewhat off-topic, as about non-US country: e.g. in Germany, taxes are automatically collected e.g. on wages, interest, dividends etc. These automatic collections are set up in a way that you cannot underpay (for those types of income). Thus, it is pretty normal to file a declaration that leads to a refund, and you cannot legally avoid the overpayment by other means than not doing things that lead to tax deduction.

Answer (score 98):

You don't "need" your refund to be as small as possible, but you usually would *want* it to be as small as possible.

The reason people say you should aim for a small refund is that getting a big refund means you paid more in taxes than you had to.  This means you gave away money that you could have done something else with.  You get the money back later as a tax refund, but you lost the ability to use it during the time the government had it.

For instance, if as you say you are getting a $1000 tax refund, that's $1000 that you are giving to the government over the course of the year.  At the end of the year, you get it back, so you end the year with $1000.  If you instead kept the money, (by paying only exactly as much tax as you owe throughout the year) you could invest it somehow, so that by the end of the year it could potentially have grown to, say, $1050.  Thus at the end of the year you would have $1050 instead of $1000.

Ideally you would have zero refund and owe zero extra at the end of the year.  However, since it is often difficult to make things work out so exactly, people often say you should aim for a small refund.

Assuming you are in the USA, if your income is only $9000 you will likely not owe any federal income tax at all, so you could claim exemption from withholding and avoid paying any tax ahead of time.  You could check this when you file your taxes by seeing if the refund you get is equal to the total of taxes withheld from your paychecks over the course of last year.

Comment: So in NZ AFAIK you have about 10 months to pay any outstanding tax at after the year end. Would it not be better to pay as little tax as possible, and invest the money until the last month? Assuming of corse there is no interest or fees on outstanding tax.

Comment: @Petah: That is a big assumption.  In the US there are indeed penalties if you significantly underpay your tax.  I would assume most countries have penalties for not paying your taxes the way you're supposed to, or else there wouldn't be much point in saying you're supposed to do it that way.

Comment: In the UK (and I suspect also the US and NZ) when individuals over-pay taxes through payroll deductions it's because the assumptions fed into the deduction calculation either are wrong to start with or else become wrong during the year. So Petah's point is in the right direction: if you have legitimate grounds to reduce your payroll deductions then you should. But the system is set up with the intention that you can't legitimately underpay by a large amount, so you don't really have the option to save a lot of money this way.

Comment: In some places, the interest that the government pays on overpaid income tax is so large that it is a quite attractive form of saving.  It was like that for me when I was living in Sweden.

Comment: So, to put it short: You just gave your government a loan. Usually it's zero-interest loan.

Comment: Personally I think it's better to err on the side of caution - to rather pay a bit too much and get refund, than to risk paying too little and get tax owed and penalties.  Yes, you could perhaps have invested the money, but seriously, would you?  After all if it's your employer which have docked your pay, then $1000 means just about $80 extra each month!  Besides, I think it's easier to invest the $1000 you got back, than "remembering" to invest $80 each month.

Comment: @Agent_L Plus it plays right into the hands of their inflationary economy - effectively, you get *less* back, even ignoring the opportunity cost.

Comment: @BaardKopperud you could raise your retirement contributions and not have to remember a thing. That $80/month would likely earn over 50k in interest in a lifetime -- not to mention company matching, if not already maxed.

Comment: Then isn't it better to underpay your taxes by a significant amount, invest that money, and then give it back before April 15?

Comment: @MartínFixman It is, but most govts have laws against that.

Comment: @MartínFixman Only if your investment returns significantly exceed the [IRS underpayment penalty](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc306.html), at which point you should have just gotten a loan and invested on margin anyway if you think that's a good idea.

Comment: @bdimag But retirement contributions are themselves pre-tax in many cases, so now you are reducing your tax burden further...

Comment: Assuming that you over-pay the tax over the whole year, you basically lose out on *amount \* annual interest rate \* /2*. For example if you had a $1000 refund and could get 5% interest on it, that would be *1000 \* 0.05 /2* or $25. (The /2 is because you wouldn't have had all the money all year, you'd have some of it for 11 months and some of it for 1, etc)

For most people, then, you're really not losing out too much - but it's still $25 you've given to the government rather than spent yourself. If you do this over your life, that's $1000 extra tax you've paid!

Comment: @gerrit - Also in Canada.  The Canada Revenue Agency [currently pays 3% interest](http://news.gc.ca/web/article-en.do?mthd=tp&crtr.page=1&nid=1024879&crtr.tp1D=1) on overpayments, which beats the hell out of savings accounts or government bonds.

Comment: @Jon Story But annual rate doesn't apply to most of what you overpay...  Assuming I've get refund in February, then yes, what I paid too much in January, February, March and April have lost me about 1 year of interest... but what I over-paid in October, November and December, have just lost me a few months of interest - which isn't much.

Comment: @BaardKopperud No, which is why you halve it, to average it over 6 months (assuming you overpaid the same amount each month).

Comment: The US pays interest on refunds held past the year in which the tax was paid. For instance, I was able to claim a first-time homebuyer credit retroactively on the previous year's taxes, and was paid interest on the amount.

Answer (score 36):

Years ago, a coworker bragged to me how his "tax guy" got him a huge refund. I told him my goal was to owe a couple thousand dollars, and that I'm glad I didn't have his guy.

In the end, your return should reflect the truth, and a good tax guy will be little better than good tax software. The bottom line is that a refund is money you lend the government, interest free. If you can owe a bit of money but avoid paying a penalty, you'll have gotten a free loan from Uncle Sam.

Given the fact that most (it seems that way, someone tell me if I'm wrong) families carry some balance on their credit cards, they are paying out 12% or more on their highest interest debt. Lending the government even $1000 for the year comes at a cost, if you file in time to get your refund by the end of March, that's an average 9 months you are out your money. 12%/yr is $90. Scale that up to $3000, the average refund, and the max 24% rate I've seen, $540 lost.  Better to adjust your withholding, and get the extra money each paycheck to pay off other debt.

Obviously, for those with no debt, their cost is minimal, perhaps 1%, but still better in your pocket for the year.

If you pay in this money every paycheck, only to feel good getting it back every March or April, while paying 18% card interest every month, that's your choice. And Stevej will support that decision, or so it seems.

EDIT - The Huffpost article Steve linked titled "[Big Tax Refunds Really Are Good](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/mark-steber/-big-tax-refunds-really-a_b_4653233.html)" ignores this debt, only focusing on the near zero rate banks offer now. The article listed 8 reasons the author felt this way. By the way, the author is the "Chief Tax Officer, Jackson Hewitt Tax Service Inc" which makes him a bit less than a disinterested third party. And all 8 of his reasons are far from compelling. "In my opinion, getting a $3,000 check is never a bad thing." This was #1, and by now you know why I disagree. Next, "More than 75 percent of all individual taxpayers get refunds year after year. It has been this way for decades.... It is unlikely that 75 percent of all taxpayers are all making bad financial decisions every year." That's enough. Rhetorical nonsense. Read the rest for yourself and decide if the next 6 reasons are any more compelling. 
Keep in mind, sellers of tax software or services have backed themselves into a corner with the "largest refund" claims. I'm sympathetic to the fact that "we'll shoot for no refund at all, in fact, our goal is for you to owe just $100" will not be their next campaign.

EDIT 2 - I gave this more thought as I started to write a near 1000 word post on this topic. I came to find that 1 in 4 employees did not deposit enough in their 401(k) to capture the full match. This is the highest lost opportunity as the potential return is an instant 100% for matched deposits. Again, it's easy to dismiss the near zero bank rates, but that's not the alternative best use for the money.

Comment: Maybe if your coworker had engaged "his guy" from the start of the tax year, instead of only to file his return, then he'd be where you are. He's basically bragging that he hired a guy to haul a huge truckload of garbage out of his front yard. Yes, that's great, but people who don't dump their garbage in their front yard don't need to do it. So pay a guy to tell you (or figure out for yourself) a better way to deal with garbage.

Comment: Nice analogy, Steve

Comment: Worse yet, that $1000 refund is more often than not blown away on extravagant purchases (it is found money, after all!) instead of being used to pay down that credit-card debt.

Comment: If you take out the part of the credit card debt I have to agree with the  JH CTO.  You aren't getting any return on your money in a bank these days.  So really it is more like a yearly savings fund.  Will people splurge part of their tax refund.  Maybe but I think they would be far less likely to spend it this way opposed to coming in monthly.  When doing budgets you wouldn't account for this.  If you set it to equal zero your balance sheet will be close to 0 at end of year.  Here you are gaining money which in most cases goes to unexpected things or savings.

Comment: @blankip - if you wish to reduce his logic to "right now your alternative investing choices are either risky or near 0%. If you have no high rate debt, this is a non-issue." I'd back off. My problem is that he ignores this outright, while any google search will tell you about all the card holders carrying debt month to month.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Do you have a reference that it's usually blown away on an extravagant purchase?  With some people this "enforced saving" will be good - otherwise they'd spend it all when they got it and end up in the same amount of credit card debt at the end of the year, but without the "windfall" to help pay it off.  If people have the discipline this is not good, but my impression is the people who get into credit card debt are disproportionately those who don't have this discipline (not always, but a higher proportion).  I'd love to see actual data on this rather than "my impression".

Comment: @Joel I have no documentary evidence but plenty of anecdotal evidence from friends, family, etc as well as with people that I meet through a money management advice program that I am involved with (I am an advisor). Tax refunds have _never_ been used to pay down credit card debt but always spent on something else. YMMV.

Comment: @DilipSarwate [This](http://www.nber.org/digest/mar09/w14753.html) is what I was thinking about - the stimulus checks under Bush were mostly just used to pay off debt, not actually spent, which was not the intent.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - I get a couple thousand back in taxes every year.  I max out my 401k, I have some money in stocks and zero cc debt...  The money I get in taxes I would never invest so it is either have it sitting in the bank earning almost nothing or the refund.  I don't think my buying habits would change much if the money was their monthly or not but my wife definitely likes to see a certain amount in savings and the low point of our savings every year does coincide with xmas... so we save more.  We never buy something based on our return, it just replenishes savings.

Comment: @blankip Congratulations on being in a state of financial health that far too many Americans do not even believe can be found in Nature any more.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - I like the advice on this site.  But I don't like that most of it is centered around those who can't control their spending habits.  I think answers should give the ideal preference, not what I would do if I were in debt and had nothing in the bank.

Comment: @blankip - IOW, you don't want the answers centered around that which is most applicable to the overwhelming majority of people.

Answer (score 20):

I would go even further:  You should want to *pay* as much as possible with your return without having to pay a penalty.  This lets you keep your money as long as possible without costing you anything extra.  You don't want to overdo it and pay fees, so leave yourself some buffer.  Still, try to get yourself in the mindset that paying at tax-time is a good thing!

Comment: The sad fact is, owning money at tax time is a major stress and financial burden that many people can't handle.  While what you say is true, the chance of someone actually saving enough money to pay their taxes at tax time _and_ having invested that money to make a small profit is very, very small.

Comment: @JPhi1618: I suppose you mean "owing" and not "owning"?

Comment: @gnasher729, Indeed.  And my edit window has passed...  Thanks

Comment: Some people are built for playing as close to the edge of the rules as possible without breaking them: they thrive as NFL defensive backs and treat the occasional call for pass interference and fine for helmet-to-helmet as all part of the job. Other people like to know they're *nowhere near* the edge, so a slight overpayment on taxes helps them sleep all year round since they won't have to rectify underpayment by any fixed deadline. That said, the questioner is in effect getting late payment of $1000 out of their $9000 annual earnings, which seems *way* too much to pay for peace of mind.

Comment: This "owe as much tax as possible" tactic could also leave you open to *very large penalties* should something go wrong when it comes time to pay - unexpected expenses, job loss or *anything* really, problems filing, late, etc

Comment: I'm really shocked and saddened by the number of comments on this thread from people who either cannot manage their money or believe that others cannot do so. In addition, it seems like people have a very pessimistic view of what these penalties are.  The penalty is some interest that's less than, say, the amount that you're probably already paying on your credit card bill.  I never suggested pushing it all the way to the edge and leaving yourself stuck - All I said was that paying is better, which is inarguably true.  Whether or not you can practically achieve that is something different.

Comment: Optimal strategy is to owe money at the end of the year, but not enough to pay any penalty.  No two ways about it.  Anything else represents suboptimal financial planning or discipline.  The OP didn't ask what's easiest...just what is **best**

Comment: Planning to owe and saving the money in T-bills (when I got a bonus that wasn't withheld) gave me no scramble but additional interest to keep.

Comment: This 'inarguable' stance is based purely on numbers, and ignores the psychology of the people. If it were all about the numbers lotteries like the powerball would not work. Consider the perspective of these people, they might not be "bad with money" but rather might want options that are more emotionally satisfying. From that perspective the opportunity cost of not investing that money has bought some happiness.

Comment: @brick In the UK if you do something which results in penalties/interest being owed, then you are placed in a higher risk category and more likely to be audited in future years. I don't know if this is the case in the USA but I would have thought so, because it is an obvious way for them to prioritise audits.

Comment: @brick To expand on Sqeaky's comments, when we talk about **best** we really should be referring to [maximising utility of money](http://tinyurl.com/86qzzrp). A rational person will allocate money to get the most utility from it, so for someone who would find it stressful to do what you propose, not doing may be the best strategy. The utility loss of stress must be weighed against the utility gain of having the money for the year. You also need to factor in the *time* and *effort* required to allocate efficiently. It may not be worth spending time to be 100% optimal with tax returns.

Comment: @JBentley The IRS, afaik, does not publish audit criteria. I can say that neither the commercial tax software that I used to use or my CPA indicate any risk and I've never been audited. I have cut it too close once or twice and paid some minimal interest in a year where my income varied a lot during the year. The difficulty of getting this close is being HUGELY exaggerated by people on this forum. This is a 15-30 min exercise once a year if you've got regular income. After the first year, it's probably even less than that. It's not some huge enterprise that you've got to actively manage daily.

Answer (score 9):

Let's say you should have paid $4000 in taxes in a year, but you paid $5000, so you get a tax return of $1000. "Somebody" thinks that you should have tried to only pay $4000 in the year and get zero tax return. I hope he or she doesn't think you should pay $5000 and mess up your tax return so you get no refund.

Once the end of the tax year is there, you should do what you can to get as much tax returned as possible. On the other hand, you should also have tried to pay less during the year - obviously every dollar you paid less is a dollar less refund.

Comment: Well, on my W4 I didn't count myself as independent.. so, only 10% of taxes is taken out of my check. Instead of 20% (if I count myself as independent)

Comment: $9000 is below the standard deduction and exemption. You should have zero tax due for the whole year. No need to withhold even $1.

Answer (score 8):

The pure numbers answer says you want the refund to be close to $0.  You can even argue, as some answers have, that you want to try to maximize the payment without receiving any sanctions for underpaying during the year.

If you trace the money, it's easy to see why.  Let's say you get a paycheck.  Tag some of the dollars for Uncle Sam.  These are the dollars that, eventually, will be given to the IRS.  Now consider the following scenarios:

- You keep all of the money in your own accounts, leveraging that money.  Perhaps your bank has a $2000 minimum deposit before incuring fees.  You used to have to keep $2k of your money in the bank, doing nothing.  Now, instead, you can put $2k of Uncle Sam's money in the bank, gaining utility from it.  Then, near tax time, you make sure you have $2k of your own money in the bank, pay Uncle Sam.
- You withold all of the money tagged for Uncle Sam.  You no longer get any benefit from that money.  However, at tax time, Uncle Sam already has all the money he's going to ask for in his coffers.
- You withold even more money.  Now, not only do you not benefit from that money, but in fact you're loosing access to money that *wasn't* tagged for Uncle Sam, but you gave it to him anyway!  Then, at tax time, he hands you back the parts that weren't tagged.  That money could have been providing leverage, such as investment or keeping banking fees away, but it didn't do so because you gave it to Uncle Sam, interest free, instead.

From the raw numbers like this, its clear that you *lose* utility by setting yourself up for a large refund check.  The money was yours the entire time, but you chose to give it to Uncle Sam instead.

However, the raw numbers are only part of the puzzle.  If you're a cold steely-gazed numbers person, they're the part that matters.  When the billionares are playing their tax evasion games, this is the only thing *they* are paying attention to.  However, real humans have a few psychological reasons they may choose to lose utility in terms of raw dollars in exchange for psychological assistance:

- Many have a hard time "earmarking" money.  If the money is in the account, they use it.  It's not ideal, but its how real people behave.  In this case, they are using the IRS as a poor quality savings account.  It's horrible fiscally, but they may be able to psychologically write it off as "its not my money," and then see a boon later.
- Some are not very good at saving for big things.  I know many individuals choose to use the IRS piggy-bank as a way to save for large things that need to be done.
- Some view the emotional trauma of being in debt to the IRS to be a sufficiently brutal scenario that they would rather be *confident* that they're covered rather than taking the time to run the numbers and arrive at the logical answer.

These attitudes exist, and may be ideal for any one person.  Obviously the financially savvy answer of "minimize your refund" is the ideal answer from a dollars and cents perspective, but its up to you to see whether that attitude is right when you account for all of the non-measurable things, like stress.  In general, I would lead anyone to "minimize your refund," but I would be remiss if I didn't include the very real psychological reasons people choose to deviate from it.

Comment: You had me at *utility*, but the use of that word implies a level of education the average person doesn't have. Can we agree on this "Understand your own cost of money, whether it be your highest rate debt, likely an 18%+ credit card, or the best return you can get investing, whichever is higher".

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I think we can agree, lumping the intangible costs in with "cost of money."  I like to pay extra attention to those, because we often forget about them when given an opportunity to crunch old numbers instead =)

Comment: True folks. We are discussing opportunity cost, and utility, and even PV/FV concepts. The fact is we should know how much tax we are paying and how much we *should* be paying. We could go further and talk about payday loans and class struggle - what it costs the poor to be $10 short, say. The major issue issue I have with using my income tax contributions as a de facto sinking fund is that I might *need* the money and not be able to access it. I am not poor, but I am asset rich with a pretty thin cash flow, every dollar helps. I can't even borrow against it.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on **when** you're setting the goal.

1) When you have finished the year and you are filling out tax forms, your goal is to get as large of a refund as possible.

2) When the year begins afresh and you are earning money and paying taxes, your goal should be roughly to pay exactly the amount of tax owed so that at the end of the year you don't have any refund or tax owed - it's the same as getting your tax refund right away rather than waiting until after you file taxes.  So you want your W4 set up appropriately (assuming you're talking about the US).

I think (1) is obvious.  For (2), imagine you start the year with the goal to get the largest possible tax refund at the end.  Well that's simple - fill out the W4 and on line 6 ("Additional amount, if any, you want withheld from each paycheck") tell them to withhold everything.  Then at the end of the year you'll get a huge refund.  Of course in the meantime, you've made an interest-free loan to the government, and you've probably had to take out a high-interest rate loan from your bank or credit card.  Obviously this is bad.

---

An argument could be made that it would be even better to slightly underpay your taxes (but not enough to owe a penalty).  Ignoring human weakness, this is correct.  If you have the discipline to set that money aside in a safe place, that's okay.  If this would cause you to spend that money (or even save less of your other money), then this is a bad idea.

So I'd really want to highlight **some of this depends on your own financial discipline** - is it better for you to have the money right away so that you can make good choices with how to use it now, or is it better for you to put the money somewhere out of reach so that you won't spend it on impulse purchases?  (and recognize that there are ways to put it out of reach and earn interest on it rather than spending it - one good choice for you would be a Roth IRA)

Answer (score 4):

Your question begins with a misunderstanding.

When you prepare your tax return (Form 1040/1040A/1040EZ) you always try to minimize your total tax bill.

When you fill out form W4 you trying to estimate how much tax will be shown on next years tax return.

The penalty for having too much tax withheld is not having the use of the money until you get a tax refund. At the moment interest rates are very low and your economic loss is the temporary loss of access to the money. One exception would be if you are carrying credit card debt. In that case you are, in effect, paying 20-30% interest to borrow money you lending to the US Treasury for 0% interest.

The penalty for having too little tax withheld is having to make a large payment with your tax return. If your pre-payments aren't at least as much as your total income tax from last year there may also be modest underpayment penalty based on the difference between your pre-payments and your total income tax from last year or this year whichever is less. A large underpayment will trigger a different larger underpayemnt penalty.

The W4 combined with the withholding rates tends to over-withhold income tax for most, but not all, taxpayers. Most people don't have enough savings to pay a large tax due, which leads to more penalties and an even larger bill. Over-witholding protects the overall tax system from the consequences of those events. People tend to be very unhappy, not quietly.

On balance your greatest economic benefit depends on whether or not you have high interest debt. If you do, then accurate and even slightly under-withholding will probably work to your advantage as long as you can pay next 4/15. If not, avoiding the chance of having any unexpected balance due next year may be more important.

Comment: Underpayment penalty is a percentage of the shortfall of your withholding plus (timely) estimated payments from 
**90%** of this year's tax or 100% (110% for higher income, 66% for farmers and fishermen) of last year's tax.
Since it's a percentage this goes up with the amount of underpayment, but I've never seen a 'different' penalty on larger underpayment. 
Although if your withholding was low *because* you claimed undeserved exemptions on W-4, there is a separate fixed penalty for that.

Answer (score 2):

Something I've not heard mentioned in any of the answers is that (at least for me) **owing some tax money is better** than having a refund from a ID theft/fraud/security aspect.

The US [IRS has been hacked several times recently](http://www.usnews.com/news/articles/2016-02-16/why-the-irs-was-hacked-again-and-what-the-feds-can-do-about-it) and there have been cases of fraudulent tax refunds being filed and tax refund checks being cashed by ID thieves. Well, if you owe a bit of tax then you're less of a target for fraudulent tax refunds being filed in your name.

Even in the case that you were unlucky enough to have had your identity stolen, at least you don't have to deal with the IRS trying to sort a mess like that up.

Thus, (IMO) it's better to owe a bit of tax, than to have a small refund, or any refund for that matter. Ideally, you want to get to zero dollars owed like you suggested, but that's often pretty hard to do. So, the next best thing is to owe a bit.

One should try to calculate tax liability quartely or if income changes, adjust your withholding, so that you get closer to zero tax.

Comment: The people committing the fraud are using your id info to file taxes, the numbers they use for income and deductions are fake. The idea i to get money before the IRS computers catch the discrepancy. They don't care what your income was, or how much you had withheld.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep There's two parts here: the risk thieves pick your identity for fraud isn't affected by your legitimate balance or even tax, but IF they do pick you then the hassle of *resolving* it is worse in the refund case.

Answer (score 1):

Having a large state return also means that there is a potential income tax liability created at the federal level for the following year, as the situation resulted from the deduction of more on one's federal return than should have been deducted. The state refund is treated as federal income in the year it is refunded.

http://blog.turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tips/is-my-state-tax-refund-taxable-and-why-90/

Answer (score 1):

Set aside any perceived positive aspects of being owed a refund and weigh those with the negatives. What are the reasons you should not have your money tied up with the IRS? You'll see that Uncle Sam does not have a good track record as a financial institution:

1. Has a history of delayed repayment.

Many thousands of refunds every year are delayed for many months due to IRS systems glitches. Yet, many people count on that refund which is not always guaranteed within the stated time-frame.

2. Is above the law

You have no legal recourse. You cannot sue the federal government for the money you lent them when they decide not to pay you back for an extended period of time. Yet, if you decide to delay paying them, they have all the power and will use it to charge you fee's that no corporate / private institution would get away with.

3. Has a history of fraud see SteveJ's answer above.

"owing some tax money is better than having a refund from a ID theft/fraud/security aspect"

4. Will not pay you interest

Again, there is zero financial incentive to lend free money to Uncle Sam, he is not a bank. The only time interest comes into play is when the refund is overdue. Even then, it is not an incentive / doesn't come close to the penalty burden on you if you don't pay your taxes on time.

I would ask the followup question: What sane person would engage in business with such a financial institution?

Answer (score 0):

I contend that there is great value in over-paying during the year and reaping a bigger refund.

I'm an engineer and understand the concept interest earned, blah blah. But for most of us, this isn't reality. The reality is that we spend what we earn, plus a little more.

At the end of each month, if the typical American has money left over - we spend it. We don't faithfully put that money that we would have payed into taxes to good use (such as savings or paying off that credit card).

Getting that big refund at the end of the year tends encourage us to make that one-time large payment to that high interest account, or to purchase that item that we otherwise wouldn't have saved for (or purchased with a credit card).

I say, give Uncle Sam the free interest - you'll have wasted that money during the year anyway - and enjoy a nice healthy refund that you can put to use for something you enjoy.

Life is just too short.

[Edit] For the nose snubbers that can't think beyond the possibility of a different perspective:
[Link1](https://www.usaa.com/inet/ent_blogs/Blogs?action=blogpost&blogkey=financialadviceblog&postkey=is_big_tax_refund_good&akredirect=true)
[Huff Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/mark-steber/-big-tax-refunds-really-a_b_4653233.html)

SteveJ

Comment: The government isn't a bank account. Put your money into a bank account, or, if you're the type that lacks self control, an account that you can't touch (CD or something). It'll grow faster, and you can get access to it (depending on the account type you chose) if an emergency comes up. And, not everyone has money left over a the end of the month, sometimes even resorting to credit cards. Having extra money may be more beneficial right now, instead of a year from now in one large lump (which is likely to be blown on some toy).

Comment: How many of those people that lack self control create a CD do you think? We are talking about real people here. Changing your allotments is something that we all have to do anyway and only takes a second. I'm not saying your wrong theoretically, it just isn't the way most people behave. BTW. I'm debt free except for mortgage.

Comment: Steve, it's not about the few cents interest. It's the fact that while lending the government this money, they are still in debt on their credit cards. You have no high interest debt, and despite an engineering degree which implies an embrace of logic over emotion, still wish to use tax withholding as a Christmas club account? No issue. The average tax refund is $3000, money better used to pay $250/mo toward that debt that others have.

Comment: I'd like to think that it is about people not being made to feel that there toes are going to fall off if they elect to have a refund. I'm a smart guy, I know what I'm doing, and I like to get a refund - I don't think there is anything wrong with it. Want to fight the government? there are much more effective ways to fight waste than that. Anyway - the discussion is degrading and I think any unbiased person will understand the point I am making - so I'll stop here....and marking me down because you have a difference in opinion is childish.

Comment: @SteveJ I'll be happy to hold your money for one year and give you a refund at the end of the year. I'll hold as much of it as you want to give me so that you can feel great when you get the refund from me too!

Comment: @Brick ; Really, you would do that. The Huff post suggest that the average interest on that money is $15 per year. You will get the contracts made up so both of us are protected and hold my money for $15? I'll take that offer. [Edit] ... and you have to make it as easy and safe for me as changing my IRS allotments .... arg, I swear accountants are lemmings!

Comment: @SteveJ As I believe JoeTaxpayer mentioned in another post in this thread - the effective interest rate will vary from person-to-person. If you have credit card debt, instead of paying that down quicker, you're costing yourself a lot more than $15 per year in most cases.

Comment: @SnakeDoc; There you go - it varies person by person. It isn't always good but it isn't always bad either, and for some people it is even better!

Comment: @SteveJ that's not exactly the sentiment I was going for. It's always bad, because everyone could be doing something better with that money - even if you're blowing the money now instead of later. Majority of folks get these huge refunds, then buy boats and other junk toys they don't need, can't afford, and won't use 6 months later. It would be far better to encourage folks to open a savings account, than to rely on the illusion of savings via overpaying on taxes. If you're one of the rare folks that puts the refund to great use - fantastic... but majority of folks don't.

Comment: @SnakeDoc But your assuming everybody will do something with that money. What the argument fails to consider is the human element. Many, perhaps most people I know don't save a penny. Were it not for their tax refund, they would never afford that washer, dryer, car repair that the desperately need. The tax refund is an admittance that humans behave in a certain way. If it gets certain people a lump sum of money that otherwise would never have the discipline to do so at the low cost of some lost interest - good for them.

Comment: @SteveJ Just to poke a hole in that argument - if these people had an extra, say $100-$400 available every month, they'd have the opportunity to save as they wouldn't be stretched so thin financially. Do what you want personally, but it's not really the smartest thing to do or rely on.

Comment: @SnakeDoc That is the opposite to a hole in the argument. If those people had the extra $100 to $400 each month, they wouldn't save it - they would spend it, often on trivial things like movies or eating out for which, at the end of the year, they would having nothing to show for it. In fact that is the crux of my argument (and that of the Huff post link). People waste the money every month and do not save as they should. A tax refund is an effective tool for many Americans to have a lump sum of money. Would it be better to save that money, yes! But the argument is about reality.

Comment: @SteveJ You think that people who are in desperate need of a car repair or appliance can wait for their tax return? No, they would just charge it to their credit cards. And then because they decided to let the government hold onto their money, they would not be able to pay off their full balance and would be forced to accumulate debt from the balance that gets carried over each month.